# What is the difference between File.ReadAllLines() and File.ReadAllText()?

Tags: c#, file, .net, file.readalllines

What is the difference between `File.ReadAllLines()` and `File.ReadAllText()`?

Comment: @AakashM - Have you tried reading the address bar? StackOverflow.com Q/A site? Its a perfectly fine question so either answer it or press the back button... sometimes 'offical' documentation doesn't provide clear clarity, thankfully we have sites like this where we can get the answers from a wide group of real world developers.

Comment: @Dal : when the official documentation doesn't provide clarity, by all means let us ask questions about it; such as in this *good* question, also asked today: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2966654 . The current question however includes no evidence that the asker has even *seen* the official documentation, hence my counter-question. Would "What does the + operator do in C#?" also be "perfectly fine", for you?

Comment: Not to forget there is also `File.ReadLines` which is lazy and hence cool.

Answer (score 110, accepted):

[`ReadAllLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalllines.aspx) returns an array of strings. Each string contains a single line of the file.

[`ReadAllText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalltext.aspx) returns a single string containing all the lines of the file.

Answer (score 18):

File.ReadAllText() returns one big string containing all the content of the file while File.ReadAllLines() returns string array of lines in the file.

Keep in mind that in case of ReadAllText "The resulting string does not contain the terminating carriage return and/or line feed."

More details are available at remarks section of [File.ReadAllText Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143368.aspx) and [File.ReadAllLines Method.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1.aspx)

Comment: You've got your wires crossed here. `ReadAllText` will contain carriage returns and line feeds from the source... `ReadAllLines` will store each line in an array without the end of line characters.

Answer (score 6):

`ReadAllText` reads it all in as one string, `ReadAllLines` reads it in as a `StringArray`.